# I uploaded apk to play store using fastlane supply however cant find apk in the list of available apks

Tags: android, react-native, fastlane

I am using Fastlane supply. After uploading apk to playstore I have notification that your update is live, and there is a date of creation of that notification. However, when I go to alpha test and press button `add from library` I don't see my apk in the list of apks. Is it permission problem, I have admin permission but I didn't create this account.